# Do we need to create screen to get permission for data sharing in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, transparency, tracking, data-sharing

Here I want to clarify for user data sharing & its flow in app.

When I say data - it includes user's data like name, sensitive info, location, etc. This is user's data that we want to share with our partner company.

So,
*Does sharing user data this come under trackin*g?

If **no**, fine.

If **yes**, we will implement AppTrackingTransparency.

Still *can we implement separate screen/prompt to request "data sharing" permission*?

Answer (score 0):

If you make a special screen to request data then it will create a good image and transparency between you and the user.